# Objective C equivalent of PHP range function?

Tags: objective-c

I want to quickly create an array of numbers from 0 to 10000 but with stepping increments of 500, for an array that looks like this:

```
@[@0, @500, @1000, ... @10000]
```

in `PHP`, this is built in to the [range](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) function, you could generate it like this: `range(0, 10000, 500)`

I'm not really looking for answers like looping over some initial array or numerically over 0-10000 and using modulus or something, I just want to know if there's a built in function or common shorthand for doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no built-in function like that in Objective-C. As you hinted, the best way to do it is by looping as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= 10000; i += 500) {
    [array addObject:@(i)];
}
```

If you want to make a method that works similarly to the [PHP range function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php): Returns an array of elements from **start** to **end**, inclusive.

Do this:

```
+ (NSArray *)rangeWithStart:(NSInteger)start end:(NSInteger)end step:(NSInteger)step {
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSInteger i = start; i <= end; i += step) {
        [array addObject:@(i)];
    }
    return [array copy];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a large array quickly, or one which is a range, then you can create an array which doesn't actually store all the values but computes them on the fly as needed.

To subclass `NSArray` you only need to implement two methods, `count` and `objectAtIndex:`, for your subclass to be a complete array.

Here is an implementation, so simple there are no comments ;-)

```
@interface RangeArray : NSArray

- (instancetype) initWithStart:(NSInteger)start end:(NSInteger)end step:(NSInteger)step;

@end

@implementation RangeArray
{
   NSInteger start, end, step;
   NSInteger count;
}

- (instancetype) initWithStart:(NSInteger)_start end:(NSInteger)_end step:(NSInteger)_step
{
   self = [super init];
   if (self)
   {
      start = _start;
      end = _end;
      step = _step;
      count = (end >= start && step > 0) || (end < start && step < 0) ? 1 + (end - start) / step : 0;
   }
   return self;
}

- (NSUInteger) count { return count; }

- (id) objectAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index { return @(start + step * index); }

@end
```

And you can generate your required range using:

```
RangeArray *range = [RangeArray.alloc initWithStart:0 end:10000 step:500];
```

HTH